# powershell csv unable to search

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to learn basic powershell loops on CSV files. Tried many tutorials or guides online but no avail. Hope you guys can help. Thanks

Here's my CSV file

[image: csv file]

Tried to loop through it to look for vpn_name and display the key but seems it won't find what I'm looking for. The path is correct since I tried to display what's inside `$c.'vpn_name'` displays list from `test` to `test3`.

```
$csv = import-csv -Path "path.csv"
foreach ($c in $csv) {
    $c.'vpn_name' -contains 'test'
}
```

Hope you guys can help. Really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: the `-contains` operator is for _collection objects_ and requires an exact match. to match `test1` with `test` you must _either_ use the `-match` regex operator OR the `-like` wildcard string operator ... with wildcard chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the csv file format is:

```
vpn_name,vpn_key
test,lksajdlksja
test1,lksajdlksja
test2,lksajdlksja
```

Secondly, use the following to search:

```
   foreach ($c in $csv) {
        $c.'vpn_name' -like '*test*'   //All three rows of the csv file return true.
    }

    foreach ($c in $csv) {
        $c.'vpn_name' -contains 'test'   //Only first row of the csv file return true.
    }
```

About your another question, please replace

```
'*$username*'
```

with

```
'*'+$username+'*'
```

Comment: can you share what's the difference? Thanks

Comment: tried using below getting same result ```$username = Read-Host "Enter username "
foreach ($c in $csv) {
    if ($c.'vpn_name' -like '*$username*') {
        write-host $c.'vpn_key'
    }
}```